# Returning a &HashMap from rust function

Tags: rust, hashmap, ownership

I am struggling to find an elegant to solution to access a nested map for read-only purposes in rust. I have a situation of this kind and ideally as example I could return a reference to an empty map (that of course doesn't work since the empty hashmap is owned by the function):

```
struct S {
    stuff: HashMap<A, HashMap<B, C>>
}

impl S {
    fn get(&self, a: &A) -> &HashMap<B,C> {
        return self.stuff.get(a).unwrap_or(&HashMap::new());
    }
}
```

There is no guarantee that the map stuff will have the key a, hence handling optionality is a must.

I would like the solution to implement the method get with this or similar signature in an efficient way (no copies/moving) because the map stuff can be quite big.

I could only think of the following solutions, but I am thinking there must be a more straightforward one:

1. Add a private field in struct S that is just an empty HashMap so that I can return a reference of. This seems a bad lazy solution.
2. Call entry(a).insert_with(|| HashMap::new()), but this requires unnecessary mutability.
3. Return Option<&HashMap>

It seems to me that the solution (3) is the best way to achieve the above, but maybe I am missing something and there is a more straightforward way?

Comment: Without any additional context (and particular constraints), I would directly have thought to `Option<&HashMap>`

Comment: Only other option I can think of is a "lazy static" empty hashmap (using `once_cell`).

Comment: `Option` is a good solution. Just to throw this out there, `Cow<'_, HashMap<B, C>>` could also work. A `Cow` is a copy-on-write object that might be a reference or might be an owned object. It would let you return a reference if the key exists and return an empty owned map when it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning `Option<&HashMap>` is idiomatic and simple.

```rs
fn get(&self, a: &A) -> Option<&HashMap<B,C>> {
    self.stuff.get(a)
}
```

Anything you might do with `&HashMap` can be done with `Option<&HashMap>`. For instance, you can check if a key is present.

```rs
if s.get(&a).map_or(false, |hm| hm.contains_key(&b)) {
    println!("key exists");
}
```

This produces `false` when `get` returns `None`, which is the same as if you call `contains_key` on an empty `HashMap`.

As a bonus, an `Option` containing a reference is always the [same size in memory as just the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/index.html#representation).

Answer (score 1):

Since the reference is immutable, you can provide a reference to a "global" `HashMap`.

```rust
fn get(&self, a: &A) -> &HashMap<B, C> {
    static GLOBAL_MAP: std::sync::OnceLock<HashMap<B, C>> = std::sync::OnceLock::new();
    return self
        .stuff
        .get(a)
        .unwrap_or(GLOBAL_MAP.get_or_init(HashMap::default));
}
```

This may be faster than using `Option` if you need to perform a lot of operations on the map.